# Building Custom Model using GLM Repeated Measures in SPSS

Tags: spss, glm, anova, mixed-models

I am looking for support using SPSS version 28, specifically regarding how to build a custom model using GLM Repeated Measures. I am trying to run a mixed analysis of covariance with one within-subjects variable and two between-subjects variables. I found SPSS documentation on the IBM website concerning my topic: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/28.0.0?topic=measures-glm-repeated-model. Although this documentation addresses my question, it does not appear to conform to what is actually available within the SPSS interface. Specifically, I would like to build a model that **contains two-way interactions and main effects**, while also **excluding a three-way interaction** (within-subjects variable x between-subjects variable x between-subjects variable). The full factorial model automatically gives you all three-way interactions, two-way interactions, and main effects.

According to the documentation above, "After selecting Custom, you can select the within-subjects effects and interactions and the between-subjects effects and interactions that are of interest in your analysis." However, when I try this, no within-subjects effects are available to put into a model. Only between-subjects variables and covariates appear.

If there is not a way to do this through the dialog boxes, is it possible to use syntax to specify a custom model containing just the two-way interactions (both within-subjects x between-subjects and between-subjects x between-subjects) and main effects? Here is the syntax for the full factorial model for my particular analysis:

```
GLM Seriousness_PG Seriousness_RG BY Personal_Exp_Role
    Years_Exp WITH Knowledge_Overall Involvement Normative_Girls
  /WSFACTOR=Bullying_Type 2 Polynomial
  /MEASURE=Seriousness_Girls
  /METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
  /PRINT=DESCRIPTIVE ETASQ HOMOGENEITY
  /CRITERIA=ALPHA(.05)
  /WSDESIGN=Bullying_Type
  /DESIGN=Knowledge_Overall Involvement Normative_Girls Personal_Exp_Role
    Years_Exp Personal_Exp_Role*Years_Exp.
```

In this model, my variables are thus:

- Bullying_Type (within-subjects factor)
- Years_Exp (between-subjects factor)
- Personal_Exp_Role (between-subjects factor)
- Knowledge_Overall; Involvement; Normative_Girls (covariates)
- Seriousness (dependent variable)

Within the context of my analysis, I want to **exclude** the Bullying_Type*Years_Exp*Personal_Exp_Role three-way interaction by building a model that contains **two-way interactions** (i.e., Bullying_Type*Years_Exp; Bullying_Type*Personal_Exp_Role; and Personal_Exp_Role*Years_Exp), **main effects** (i.e., Bullying_Type; Years_Exp; and Personal_Exp_Role), and **covariates** (i.e., Knowledge_Overall; Involvement; Normative_Girls). I do not see anything within the syntax that specifies the three-way interaction in order to remove it.

I am using the SPSS Standard version 28 on a Mac. I've seen this question posed previously on various forums, and it seems that earlier SPSS versions did not allow you to include within-subjects effects in custom models.

Also, I am looking to build this custom model specifically using GLM Repeated Measures - either dialog boxes or syntax. I know that it might be possible to use multilevel modeling or the MIXED command, but right now I am looking for a solution specific to ANOVA (in my case, I have a three-way mixed ANCOVA).

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

By the way, does anyone have a contact email for SPSS so that someone at the company might be able to tell me why their documentation does not line up with what is available within the program? I contacted the email included on the documentation I linked above, but it seems to be a generic feedback email address, and no one has gotten back to me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when you add three factors into the GLM, you automatically get the three-way interaction in the output. It is kind of the essence of the model.

A solution could be to run separate models for each two-way interaction you want to investigate.

Other than that, you could run the 3-way model and just disregard the three-way interaction if it is not part of your hypotheses. I don't think there is anything wrong with that. I have regularly ran ANOVAs that included various effects that I was not interested in, and only focused on the relevant output. It is important to have clear hypotheses a priori, to prevent any unexpected yet irrelevant effects from throwing you of course.

With regards to contacting IBM about their documentation: I'm afraid that is a useless endeavor. After a recent update I contacted IBM multiple times to ask about which formulas they use for their calculations, as this was not in their documentation, and never got a response either.